# Auto refeashing DIv cause jquery inside div not to work

Tags: jquery, html, refresh

I have the the following code

```
// hover show delete and refer button
    $('.friendsArea').livequery("mouseenter", function(e){
        $(this).children("a.delete").show();            
        $("a.PostShowHide_link", this).show();                      
    }); 

    // mouseout hide delete and refer button
    $('.friendsArea').livequery("mouseleave", function(e){
        $('a.delete, a.PostShowHide_link').hide();  
    });
```

To show and hide links for a list of records on mouseover and mouseout

I am working on an auto refresh similar to that of Facebook and Twitter 
I'm using the this code below to refresh to load content into a div and refresh it

```
var auto_refresh = setInterval(
    function (){
    $('#posting').load('posts.php').fadeIn("slow");
    }, 10000); // refresh every 10000 milliseconds  
});
```

But when ever the div is refreshed by the above code the links which use to show on mouseover are no longer shown

Comment: Is #posting receiving an element of .friendsArea class?

Comment: #posting is the main div which is refreshed it contains the individual posts .friendsArea which contains the individual links

Answer (score 0, accepted):

solved it instead of using ".livequery()" I reverted to using .live() now all jquery works